# Using a scheduled powershell task to run remote script timeouts

Tags: powershell

I need to access an import script located at "http://site.com/script.aspx", and I have currently setup up a powershell script doing this, the problem is the script probably takes 10minuttes to finish, and this causes the GetResponse to tiemout with : "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"

```
$global:url= "http://site.com/script.aspx"
#$myHttpWebRequest = [system.net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
#$myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 600000 # dosent seem to do whats needed
#$myHttpWebResponse = $myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have to go through a proxy to reach the internet on your network? If so, how is this configured for the user account under which your task is executing?

Comment: No, not going through a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this right, the PowerShell script is making a request to `script.aspx` that runs for 10 minutes at which point the web request throws an exception stating that the request has reached the timeout limit and has been terminated?

If so, this is not something that PowerShell has any control over. That is controlled (probably) by a setting on the server at `site.com`. I would start by looking at the `web.config` file for that `script.aspx` page.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- increase timeout to 15 minutes -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont have any direct access to modifying site.com, so that solution wouldnt fit me.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped using powershell, and instead got wget running from a batch file.